# Sending more than one request to a TCP server fails

Tags: go, tcp

I'm trying to send more than one request to a TCP server in Go but for some reason the second request is never sent, even if it is identical to the first one.

This is the server:

```
func StartServer(host string) {

    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", host)
    log.Println("Starting server on:", host)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    defer l.Close()
    log.Println("Server is running...")

    for {
        // Listen for an incoming connection.
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
        }
        // Handle connections in a new goroutine.
        fmt.Println("got a request")
        go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}
```

And this is the function in the client that sends the requests to the server:

```
func (u *User) ConnectToServer(host string, partner string) {
    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", host)
    fmt.Fprintf(conn, "message1\n")
    fmt.Fprintf(conn, "message2\n")
}
```

**EDIT**: In the handleRequest function I read the input as follows:

```
 // Handles incoming requests.
func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {

    rec, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error reading:", err.Error())
    }

    log.Println("Got message: ", rec)

    // Send a response back to person contacting us.
    conn.Write([]byte("Message received."))
    // conn.Close()
}
```

Which according to the documentation only takes the first part before the first line break detected so I believe the second message is ignored because of this. How can I read both messages? Should I change the delimiter in the client maybe?

Comment: The server logs when a new connection is accepted. Does the client dial more than one connection?  Show more of the client code.

Comment: @ceriselimon The client only dials one connection.I think I narrowed down by problem, will update the post now.

Comment: The application is discarding buffered data. Create one bufio.Reader and reuse it. Please post all of the relevant code.

Comment: @ceriselimon updated the post again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server should read multiple lines given that the client sends multiple lines.  Use [bufio.Scanner](https://godoc.org/bufio#Scanner) to read lines:

```
func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
   defer conn.Close()
   scanner := bufio.NewScanner(conn)
   for scanner.Scan() {
      fmt.Printf("Got message: %s\n", scanner.Bytes())
      conn.Write([]byte("Message received."))
   }
   if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("error reading connection: %v\n", err)
   }
}
```

Some notes about the code:

- To prevent a resource leak, the function closes the connection on return.
- The scanner loop breaks on error reading the connection. If the error is not io.EOF, then the function logs the error.
- `bufio.Reader` can also be used to read lines, but bufio.Scanner is easier to use.

Comment: This works however I had to change the scanner so that it uses the connection instead of `os.Stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

In `handleRequest()`, you call `ReadString()` on the bufio Reader. Let's look at the [docs](https://godoc.org/bufio#Reader.ReadString):

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input,
>   returning a string containing the data up to and including the
>   delimiter. If ReadString encounters an error before finding a
>   delimiter, it returns the data read before the error and the error
>   itself (often io.EOF). ReadString returns err != nil if and only if
>   the returned data does not end in delim. For simple uses, a Scanner
>   may be more convenient.

Considering the packets you're sending are terminated by a `\n`, you must call `ReadString()` twice on the same reader. You probably want to call `ReadString()` in a loop until it returns an error. Make sure to distinguish `io.EOF`, then.

Here's a [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pFrK_j8KMR1) with some inspiration. Note: it appears the playground does not allow TCP sockets, so you will have to run this elsewhere.

Comment: Is this the correct way to do it? I updated the post again maybe you can help me.

Comment: @ninesalt Yes it is.